# Error in query for google distance matrix api

Tags: android, xml, api

I am trying to call google distance matrix api but getting an error as illegal query at 115. here is my code:

```
protected Document doInBackground(LatLng... latlng) {

        String destinationURL = "";
        //  ASSUMING THAT FIRST LATLNG PASSED IS ALWAYS A SOURCE LOCATION
        for(int index = 1; index < latlng.length; index ++)
        {
            destinationURL += latlng[index].latitude +"," + latlng[index].longitude;
            if(index+1 != latlng.length)
            {
                destinationURL+= "|";
            }
        }
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?" 
                + "origins=" + latlng[0].latitude + "," + latlng[0].longitude  
                + "&destinations=" + destinationURL
                + "&sensor=false&mode=walking";
```

If I paste the url given above then this is the result: [URL link of query](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=35.777418,-78.677666&destinations=35.78036,-78.67816%7C35.787515,-78.670456&sensor=false&mode=walking)

Error details: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 115: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=35.777418,-78.677666&destinations=35.78036,-78.67816|35.787515,-78.670456&sensor=false&mode=walking`

Code for calling above url:

```
 try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
```

Any help is v.much appreciated.

Comment: Throwing it into a browser works.  Does the | need to be encoded into %7C?

Comment: I am not sure, I am using it in android application and it crashes at :  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);. totally stuck

Comment: You were right @Gabe Sechan. I just noticed that "|" pipe character converts to %7C after URLencoder.encode(|). I did not get first time when you said if | needs to be encoded into %7C but now understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple of tries found the issue here. I was using pipe character "|" for joining the latitude and longitude. Note pipe character was simply a string. **However in order to add pipe character in URL use URLEncoder** Final string to add:

```
destinationURL += latlng[index].latitude +"," + latlng[index].longitude;
if(index+1 != latlng.length)
    {
        try {
            destinationURL+=  URLEncoder.encode("|", "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
```

It worked successfully.